# modern.IE to test site behind firewall

Tags: internet-explorer-11, modern.ie

I am looking to test the browser compatibility of some web apps hosted behind a firewall.

I was thinking that after I installed and setup modern.IE from GitHub on my machine which is behind the same firewall the apps are behind (note: the apps aren't on my machine, not accessible via localhost), I would be able to test them...but so far I have been plagued with issues.

Before I ask this great stackoverflow site with questions diagnosing those issues (I've been reading and trying suggestion after suggestion for days, from all over the web), I would like to confirm that what I am trying to do is in fact possible.

If modern.IE is properly installed and configured on a machine behind a firewall, can it be used to test sites/apps which are also behind that firewall but NOT locally available on that machine?

Thank you for your time.

**UPDATE, with details of the issues I've been experiencing, some steps i've taken, and my latest results:**

I've installed the modern.IE app multiple times using npm/nodejs, each time resolving prior installation issues such as setting the proxy, getting applicable vcbuild.exe file(s), installing Python, updating path, etc. Each time i did a new installation, i started with a fresh version of the modern.IE files.

-After my latest installation, i received no errors but did get the following warnings, after researching them, i could not find a solution to resolve them, but I proceeded, with the hopes that they were not going to cause fatal issues:

> C:\ie11\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1066)
>   : warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int',
>   possible loss of data
>   [C:\ie11\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify\build\contextify.vc
>   xproj]
>   C:\ie11\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1083)
>   : warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int',
>   possible loss of data
>   [C:\ie11\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify\build\contextify.vc
>   xproj]
>   C:\ie11\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1114)
>   : warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int',
>   possible loss of data
>   [C:\ie11\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify\build\contextify.vc
>   xproj]
>   C:\ie11\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1146)
>   : warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int',
>   possible loss of data
>   [C:\ie11\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify\build\contextify.vc
>   xproj] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\include\xlocale(337): wa rning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
>   [C:\ie11\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify\build\context
>   ify.vcxproj]
>   C:\ie11\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify\node_modules\nan\nan.h(934):
>   warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from '__int64' to 'int',
>   possible l oss of data
>   [C:\ie11\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify\build\contextif
>   y.vcxproj]

Here are the types of results I get when running modern.IE on different types of sites:

external/open site, google.com:

> {   "statusCode": "No response",   "message": "Error found: Error:
>   connect ECONNREFUSED" }

internal site, behind the firewall which my computer is also behind, xxxx.xxxx.com, I got the following error:

```
C:\ie11>node app.js Server started on port 1337 To scan a private url go to http://localhost:1337/ and follow the instructions

C:\ie11\lib\checks\check-compatlist.js:34
        return this[0].attribs['http-equiv'].toLowerCase() === 'x-ua-compatibl
                      ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'attribs' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\ie11\lib\checks\check-compatlist.js:34:23)
    at filterFn (C:\ie11\node_modules\cheerio\lib\api\traversing.js:288:20)
    at Function.filter (C:\ie11\node_modules\cheerio\node_modules\lodash\dist\lo dash.js:3150:15)
    at exports.filter (C:\ie11\node_modules\cheerio\lib\api\traversing.js:298:17 )
    at Object.initiate [as check] (C:\ie11\lib\checks\check-compatlist.js:33:51)

    at C:\ie11\app.js:166:41
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at C:\ie11\app.js:164:15
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

after looking into the above error a bit, i removed check-compatlist.js from /lib/checks/, this yielded some positive yet puzzling results....

when checking google.com, i still get the same error as indicated above...but, now i am able to scan our internal sites, minus the functionality  the check-compatlist.js file would have offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should be possible. I think there may have been some recent change to the server that is causing submitted results to not generate a report. See https://github.com/InternetExplorer/modern.IE-static-code-scan/issues/50 and please add whatever you can to help diagnose the issue.

Comment: Dave, thank you for your response. I was able to end up scanning the local sites in the capacity mentioned above in my update. hopefully the steps i took will help others. giving you the correct answer check mark since you quickly and correctly answered the original question. thank you again.

Comment: OBTW the local scan will show you the JSON output from the scan, the names are kind of descriptive so you may be able to just read them directly, or figure them out from viewing a report at the site.